# Sorting logs (from Loki) on Grafana

Tags: logging, grafana, grafana-loki, promtail

Scenario:
The logs are in following format:

```
<SequenceID> <Level> <Message>
```

I have a requirement to sort the logs based on the SequenceID at Grafana.

Background: I am using promtail to ship logs where I create labels for SequenceID and Level.
However, I am unable to find any valid visualization/transformation option (panel/widget) at Grafana Dashboard that would help me in creating a table where I can sort the log entries based on the sequenceID.

Also note: The logs are generated at microsecond level, hence can't rely on timestamp.

PS:
When adding transformation "Labels to fields" for the label "SequenceID", I get below error:
Pls note:

- There are multiple values in the dropdown below.
- There's only one value in the table where it doesn't make sense to sort.
  [image: Sorting based on Label in Grafana]

Comment: just a note, having a sequence_id label is probably not a good design if you have many values for that. You're going to have  a log stream explosion which will impact performance: https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/best-practices/

Comment: I agree.  Too many label and value combination leads to too many streams - This results in large index and small chunks in log store. This in turn reduces the performance.
Any best practice/suggestions to overcome above?

Comment: I noted there's a major difference between specifying labels at log processing time in Log shipper (e.g. Promtail) vs extracting label values through a pattern parser. The latter is at Log query time and doesn't result in high cardinality. This solution may not be best fit for above case but still is a noticeable point. 
Reference: https://grafana.com/blog/2021/08/09/new-in-loki-2.3-logql-pattern-parser-makes-it-easier-to-extract-data-from-unstructured-logs/

Answer (score 1):

Do the following steps:

- Select "Table" visualization
- Select "Label to fields" transformation
- Click in the "sequenceID" column name to change the order.

Comment: Hi @Marcelo, Please find the screenshot updated in the original question.  The issue is : There are multiple values in the dropdown below.
There's only one value in the table where it doesn't make sense to sort.
Sorry, couldn't attach image in comment.

Answer (score 1):

Sort Example

Step 1: Choose a new dashboard
[image]
Step 2: Add a new panel
[image]
Step 3: query command (example: {job="localhost_logs"} |= "GGGG") and choose the switch to table
[image]
Step 4:  Transform (Extract fields)
[image]
[image]
Step 5: Add transformation(Organize fields)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Selected "Table" visualization.
The transformation steps are as below:

- **Reduce**

  Mode: Series to rows

  Calculations: "Step"

  Enable - Label to fields

Further, I used **Filter data values** and **Filter by name** transformation stages to filter the empty rows and remove a few columns.

[image: Transformation for ordering of logs based on label]